# All in when you are chip leader

Tags: all-in

Scenario: I am chip leader and say "All In". The only other player left in the game calls, even though he only has half the chips I do. All my chips are pushed in. I never measure my chip count against his. I just said "All In" and put my chips in. The only other player puts his in to call (even though he has less). He wins the hand easily. Do I lose all my chips now? Or do I just lose as many chips as he had?

Answer (score 4):

You lose as many chips as he had, the rest of chips are considered the same as an uncalled raise and are returned to you.

Comment: So I do not lose all my chips even though I said "I'm All In"? Plus I pushed my whole stack of chips in..

Comment: @zach No, you do not lose them. A player can only win as much as they've contributed to the pot from each of the other players in the hand. That is why side pots are created sometimes too.

Comment: A player can only win money he can cover. If you go all in with one chip, and all 9 opponents go all in for over a million, you win (assuming you win) 10 chips--yours and one from each other player. If you can't cover the bet, you can't win it.